# Why does batch norm uses exponentially weighted average (EWA) instead of simple average at test time?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, moving-average, batch-normalization

I was watching a [lecture by Andrew Ng on batch normalization](https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/FsoNw/batch-norm-at-test-time). When discussing the inference (prediction) on a test it is said that an exponentially weighted average (EWA) of batch normalization parameters is used. My question is: why use exponentially weighted average instead of a "simple" average without any weights (or, to be precise, with equal weights)?

I intuit that:

1. the latest batch is computed on weights being the closest to the final ones therefore we want it to influence the data at test time the most,
2. at the same time we do not want to get rid significant part of data used for previous training, so we let them influence predictions but in smaller degree (smaller weights).

Answer (score 0):

cant comment so i post

im not sure if question is about usage, but can try:

1. i think, for example outliers, interfere original signal.

- if outliers are like some exterior errors, its good to gave them small weight, so model copy signal without outliers.
- or, opposite, if need to model errors, give them high weights.

2. in case of, importance, 1 data can have weights from another data .. for example, if mom is angry, its more danger, than when kids are...or when childrens are at hungry level, its needed to fix it faster then when dad is.. data points have known importance
3. yes, you mentioned good cases too. if weighted meaning bring better results, its good to use it
   (i mean, for example i worked with opposite case dataset- where model build on older points bring much better results than one build on newer points
   .. it was about seeing indata relationship/structure .. model was just structure discovered/build on/as result/from previous tests/analyzing
4. exponentially .. sometimes, using log on data, decrease "chaotic" variance .. but exponential is used in "boom" cases, like "hype", 1 day 100 customers, another day 250, another 550 .. etc-just exponential growth (numbers i just guessed, they are wrong :D .. if data behave exponentialy, modeling them so is good imho :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the main reason is smoothness. When an outlier leaves the moving window of the simple average, it may lead to a big move in the parameter. EWMA produces smoother parameters in this case because rather than dropping off, the outlier's influence gradually declines.

In case of batch norm I don't see the reason why the last batch should have the higher influence than previous ones. It is uncommon to feed less relevant batches first into the queue. You would expect that batches are random, and their influence shouldn't be different.

The memory and computational complexity argument for fixed moving window size is not relevant here either. Both are negligible compared to all other stuff you store in RAM and calculate in each batch.  These are just drops in bucket. If instead of the moving window you'd like to use entire training sample then this argument becomes completely irrelevant due to recurrent formulas used for computation of means and variance.

Comment: (1) An outlier can fall into the last batch on which the model is trained. In such case, parameters from the last batch would influence the estimation greatly (since their weight would the highest). However, it is intuitively less probable that an outlier falls into the last batch than to any batch in training, therefore it's less probable than the estimations of batch norm parameters from the last batch will be highly biased by an outlier. Is you argument on smoothness based on such assumption?

Comment: (2) Regarding the second argument, maybe I did not put my thoughs clearly enough. I was thinking rather of significance of *weights* computed on the basis of the last batch, not the batch itself. I agree that the exact values falling into the last batch do not bear greater significance than any other (unless there is/are outlier(s), in which case my point from point (1) stands).

(3) Not sure why you mentioned memory and computational complexity. I presume that it was raised to just point out that it does not matter in case anyone wondered.